# Angular: ng-repeat calculate data in view

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I am writing an angular website, but I have the following problem. I have 2 data arrays that I get from my json files.

I use an ng-repeat to go over my projects in my html file, and I use another ng-repeat to go over my projects.languages.
Now what I want to do is to make it that for every language I find I am going to search in the languages data
and get the other information.

**How can I easly get the language in the ng-repeat, I need to also calculate in that the data maybe not avaible yet,
because I get the json data async.**

*This is the code I have right now:*

```
<div class="container-fluid contentcontainer">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3" ng-repeat="project in projects">
      <a href="#/project/{{$index}}" class="thumbnail">
        <img ng-src="{{project.img}}" ng-alt="{{project.name}}" />
        <div class="caption">
          <div class="languageoverlay">
            <span ng-repeat="language in projects[$index].languages">
               <img ng-src="img/languages/android.png" ng-alt="{{language}}" />
               <font ng-show="!$last">+</font> 
            </span>
          </div>
          <h3>{{project.name}}</h3>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!--this is just to try, don't need to use this-->
<h1>{{getLanguage("CSharp")}}</h1>
```

*App.js*

```
app.service('projectService', ['$http', '$q', function($http, $q) {
  var projectsDeferred = $q.defer();
  var languagesDeferred = $q.defer();

  $http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'json/projects.json',
    cache: true
  }).then(function(data) {
      projectsDeferred.resolve(data.data.projects);
  });

  $http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'json/projects.json',
    cache: true
  }).then(function(data) {
      languagesDeferred.resolve(data.data.languages);
  });

  this.getProjects = function(){
    return projectsDeferred.promise;
  };

  this.getLanguages = function(){
    return languagesDeferred.promise;
  };
}]);

app.controller('ProjectsController', ['$scope', 'projectService', function($scope, projectService) {
  $scope.projects = {};
  $scope.languages = {};

  var promise = projectService.getProjects();
  promise.then(function(data) {
      $scope.projects = data;
  });
  var promise = projectService.getLanguages();
  promise.then(function(data) {
      $scope.languages = data;
  });

  // This was a try, don't need to use this
  $scope.getLanguage = function(name) {
    array.forEach(function(element) {
      if (element.name == name) {
        $scope.push(element);
      }
    }, $scope.languages);
  };
}]);
```

*languages.json*

```
{
   "result":"SUCCESS",
   "resultMessage":"",
   "languages":[
      {
         "name":"CSharp",
         "FullName":"C#",
         "img":"img/languages/csharp.png"
      },
      {
         "name":"Android",
         "FullName":"Android",
         "img":"img/languages/android.png"
      },
      {
         "name":"VisualStudio",
         "FullName":"Visual Studio",
         "img":"img/languages/visualstudio.png"
      }
   ]
}
```

*projects.json*

```
{
   "result":"SUCCESS",
   "resultMessage":"",
   "projects":[
      {
         "name":"Test1",
         "img":"img/projects/photo-1453060113865-968cea1ad53a.jpg",
         "languages":["Android"]
      },
      {
         "name":"Test2",
         "img":"img/projects/photo-1454165205744-3b78555e5572.jpg",
         "languages":["Android"]
      },
      {
         "name":"Test3",
         "img":"img/projects/photo-1457305237443-44c3d5a30b89.jpg",
         "languages":["CSharp","VisualStudio"]
      },
      {
         "name":"Test4",
         "img":"img/projects/photo-1457612928689-a1ab27da0dad.jpg",
         "languages":["CSharp","VisualStudio"]
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: Try this.   <div ng-repeat="project in projects">  <div ng-repeat="language in project.languages"> </div></div>

Comment: For reference : http://jsfiddle.net/vojtajina/u75us/

Comment: I don't like how do you pollute the scope with database data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy piece:

First don't use $q just use $http

```
app.service('projectService', ['$http', '$filter', function($http, $filter) {
  function callLanguages(languages) {
    return $http({
      method: 'GET',
      url: 'json/projects.json',
      cache: true
    }).then(function (response) {
      return buildProjectWithLanguages(response.data.projects, languages);
    });
  }

  function buildProjectWithLanguages (projects, languages) {
    return projects.map(function (p) {
      var langs = p.languages.map(function (l) {
        var matchLangs = $filter('filter')(languages, { name: l });
        if (matchLangs.length) {
          return matchLangs[0];
        } else {
          return { FullName: l };
        }
      });
      p.languages = langs;
      return p;
    });
  }

  this.getProjects = function(){
    return $http({
      method: 'GET',
      url: 'json/languages.json',
      cache: true
    }).then(function(response) {
      return callLanguages(response.data.languages);
    });
  };
}]);
```

then simplify your controller

```
app.controller('ProjectsController', ['$scope', 'projectService', function($scope, projectService) {
  $scope.projects = [];
  projectService.getProjects(function (projects) {
    $scope.projects = projects;
  });
}]);
```

and finally change your html to this:

```
<div class="container-fluid contentcontainer">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3" ng-repeat="project in projects">
      <a href="#/project/{{$index}}" class="thumbnail">
        <img ng-src="{{project.img}}" ng-alt="{{project.name}}" />
        <div class="caption">
          <div class="languageoverlay">
            <span ng-repeat="language in project.languages">
               <img ng-src="{{language.img}}" ng-alt="{{language.FullName}}" />
               <font ng-show="!$last">+</font> 
            </span>
          </div>
          <h3>{{project.name}}</h3>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have one problem with the awnser, for some reason it doesn't get to function (projects) { $scope.projects = projects; }, but the rest of the code is actually called. I hit the  return p; breakpoint for everyproject with the correct data in it.

Answer (score 1):

I really loved your awnser, but I made another approach with directives. I tested your awnser and it looks like a correct awnser.

This is what I did:

*projects-directive.html*

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3" ng-repeat="project in projects">
    <a href="#/project/{{$index}}" class="thumbnail">
      <img ng-src="{{project.img}}" ng-alt="{{project.name}}" />
        <div class="caption">
          <languages languagenames="project.languages"></languages>
          <h3>{{project.name}}</h3>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

*languages-directive.html*

```
 <div class="languageoverlay">
    <span ng-repeat="language in languages">
        <img ng-src="{{language.img}}" ng-alt="{{language.FullName}}" />
        <font ng-show="!$last">+</font> 
    </span>
</div>
```

*app.js*

```
app.service('projectService', ['$http', '$filter', function($http, $filter) {
  this.getLanguages = function() {
    return $http({
      method: 'GET',
      url: 'json/languages.json',
      cache: true
    });
  }

  this.getProjects = function(){
    return $http({
      method: 'GET',
      url: 'json/projects.json',
      cache: true
    })
  };
}]);

app.directive('projects', ['projectService', function(projectService) {  
  return {
     restrict: 'E',
     templateUrl:  "directives/projects-directive.html",
     scope: {
        limitto: "=?"
     },
     controller: function($scope)
     {
       projectService.getProjects().then(function(response) {
         projects = response.data.projects;
         if (angular.isDefined($scope.limitto))
         {
           $scope.projects = projects.slice(0, $scope.limitto);
         } else {
           $scope.projects = projects;
         }
       });
     }
  }
}]);

app.directive('languages', ['projectService', '$filter', function(projectService, $filter) {
  return {
     restrict: 'E',
     templateUrl:  "directives/languages-directive.html",
     scope: {
        languagenames: "="
     },
     controller: function($scope)
     {
       projectService.getLanguages().then(function(response) {         
         $scope.languages = $scope.languagenames.map(function (l) {
          var matchLangs = $filter('filter')(response.data.languages, { name: l });
          if (matchLangs.length) {
            return matchLangs[0];
          } else {
            return { FullName: l };
          }
        });
       });
     }
  }
}]);

app.controller('PortfolioController', ['$scope', 'projectService', function($scope, projectService) {
  $scope.projectlimit = 4;
}]);

app.controller('ProjectsController', ['$scope', 'projectService', function($scope, projectService) {

}]);
```

How to call the directive:

```
<projects></projects>
```

and if you want to limit it, you can add parameter:

```
<projects limitto="projectlimit"></projects>
```